# Why does putty open a session on port 36556

Tags: server, ssh, putty

I'm working locally on win10 with git-bash. I'm interested in setting up some basic security on an ubuntu 16.4 vps that I'm working on. I'm reading through https://www.codelitt.com/blog/my-first-10-minutes-on-a-server-primer-for-securing-ubuntu/ and http://plusbryan.com/my-first-5-minutes-on-a-server-or-essential-security-for-linux-servers.

I'm able to login with putty but not python's fabric library. I've turned off UFW and i'm trying to figure out what is going on . when I look at the ssh system logs  after logging in with putty at

```
sudo vim /var/log/auth.log
```

I see:

```
 17:38:03 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by deploy(uid=0)
 Jun 13 17:39:55 server sshd[963]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user deploy
 Jun 13 17:40:22 server sshd[1037]: Accepted password for deploy from xx.xx.xx.xx port 36556 ssh2
 Jun 13 17:40:22 server sshd[1037]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user deploy by (uid=0)
 Jun 13 17:40:37 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
 Jun 13 17:40:40 server sudo:   deploy : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/deploy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status sshd
```

regarding my login:

```
Accepted password for deploy from xx.xx.xx.xx port 36556 ssh2
```

Why Am I listed in logging in  on port 36556 . I thought I was logging in at port 22.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know what pam_unix means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 36556 is the source port at xx.xx.xx.xx that putty is using to connect to the destination port 22 at your server